# Golang cmd command in windows

Tags: go, cmd

I am trying to run cmd command within golang, but getting no output. I am trying to install npm packages, set environment variable via golang but not able to do, can someone help

```
package main
import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        //"os"
        "os/exec"
)

const ShellToUse = "cmd"
func Shellout(command string) (error, string, string) {
    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command(ShellToUse, "-c", command)
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    return err, stdout.String(), stderr.String()
}
func main() {
     var err, out, errout = Shellout("npm install -g rimraf")    
     if err != nil {
         log.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
     }
     fmt.Println("--- stdout ---")
     fmt.Println(out)
     fmt.Println(errout)
}
```

Expected output I feel should be installing rimraf package but it doesn't. It doesn't give any errout but out has output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1016]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\jhamuk2\Desktop> // This also the output and there is same path below which shows output ended.
```

Comment: I don't think you need to name the shell to use. Just exec the command: `exec.Command("npm", "install")`.

Comment: 2020/09/01 14:35:47 error: exec: "npm install -g rimraf": executable file not found in %PATH%, it's giving this error if I remove cmd do I need to add up something in environment variables as well ? I am new to windows/cmd actually.

Comment: Then `npm` is not installed globally. Did you open the commandline yourself and try to just execute `npm`? You would have to add npm folder to your PATH, yes.

Comment: yes it's added globally I can run npm install -g rimraf inside cmd without any issue, I uninstalled it as well and checking with golang whether it gets installed or not and it doesn't.

Comment: Which PATH did you add it to? Global or user path? AFAIK, windows has different sections for environment variables...

Comment: User one and not system one.

Comment: Try the system PATH... Might be run as a different user...

Comment: Ya actually I don't have system access, will try some way. For Mac it had worked for me as well, windows it isn't working :/. Anyways Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on windows so I can't be 100% sure:

This is how I'd call the command above on Mac and knowing Go it will most likely be the same on windows (or very similar).

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install", "-g rimraf")
    fmt.Println("> " + cmd.String())
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
```